# Energy per symbol calculation

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, snr, signal-power, symbol-energy

I am having trouble calculating my Energy per symbol and Es/No. Using these parameters and equation

$N_s = $Number Symbols

$R_s = $Symbol Rate

$T_s = $Symbol Time

$sps = $samples per symbol

x = signal = QAM-16 with no noise added

Then using these, two equations:

$E_s = E_{total} / N_s = sum(abs(x)^2) / N_s $

$E_s=P_{avg} / (sps/R_s)  = P_{avg} sps T_s$

This second equation comes from Energy = Power x Time. So Energy per symbol = Power x Time for Symbol, but my symbol spans more samples because its upsampled, one symbol spans sps samples. So Energy per symbol = Power x time for symbol x sps.

Where
$P_{avg} = sum(abs(x)^2) / N $

N = Number Samples

I have tried both equations after the RRC transmit and after the RRC receive filters, both times these equations give two different answers.

First equation gives a very large number and the second is incredibly small number in comparison. Ive tried removing sps from the second equation but does not get anywhere close to first equation.

Ultimately I need to work out Es/No and I cant get Es right.  Any thoughts please? :/

Comment: I've tried to help you before, with little success; I will just provide a hint. If the RRC filter response $p(t)$ is normalized so that its energy is 1, then the energy of  $ap(t)$ is $|a|^2$. This is true for any linear modulation.

Comment: I don't think so with this, you provided answers to setting up RRC which was great as I have that working. But the energy per symbol. I can't normalise the RRC filter, because I am trying to calculate energy per symbol of any signal that has gone through the RRC and then has channel effects like impairments. So I need to derive energy per symbol

Comment: You are trying to calculate $\frac{E_s}{N_0}$ from the time domain signal after the RRC is applied?

Comment: Just Es at the moment, I've tried the two equations after transmit RRC is applied and also after the recieve RRC is applied.  I just find it peculiar that the two equations I listed above seem fundamental the way to do it but both give different answers whenever in the chain I use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation, $ \frac{1}{N_s}\sum |x[n]|^2 $, is correct. Applying the RRC filter kind of smears the energy of the symbol over several samples so that when you add them all back up again you get $E_s$, and of course divide by $N_s$ for multiple symbols. The RRC filter should be normalized as someone in the comments noted.

The second equation I can't say much as it is not clear how you compute $P_{avg}$. Secondly, dimensional analysis is a fancy way of saying writing out the units and seeing what cancels out. For example, in the second equation:

$$\text{sps }T_s\rightarrow \frac{\text{samples}}{\text{symbol}}\frac{\text{seconds}}{\text{symbol}}=\frac{\text{(samples)(seconds)}}{(\text{symbol})^2}$$

I've found this method useful as a "sanity check" for myself many times. The above units should suggest to you that something is amiss (also why do you need two equations for the same quantity?).

**Edit**
The question was updated to include definition of $P_{avg}$. The OP is computing average power *per sample* and trying to convert it to average power per symbol. Again, write out the units it becomes clear:

$$\frac{\text{energy}}{\text{sample}}\frac{\text{samples}}{\text{symbol}}=\frac{\text{energy}}{\text{symbol}} $$

```
sps = 4;
Ns = 100;
Es = 10;
rrc = rcosdesign(0.25, 6, sps, 'sqrt');
s = sqrt(Es)*qammod(randi([0, 15], Ns, 1), 16, 'UnitAveragePower', true);
x = upfirdn(s, rrc, sps);

equation1 = sum(abs(x).^2)/Ns;
equation2 = sum(abs(x).^2)/length(x)*sps;
```

Comment: I added to post where I get average power. Also, Average power x Time = Energy . Average power  x Symbol Time = Energy per symbol.    However my symbol time is upsampled by sps, so the symbol spans sps*Ts. Symbol Energy = Power x Symbol Time x sps

Comment: @NatalieJohnson How are you upsampling a continuous variable (time)? The symbol lasts for the symbol duration $T_s$, that is it. See my edit about your equation 2.